# Proving $\int_{a}^{b}( f+g) = \int_{a}^{b} f + \int_{a}^{b} g$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, riemann-integration

My textbook does the proof in a different way. Here's my attempt:

---

Since $f,g$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ then there is a family of partitions $\{P_n\}$ and $\{Q_n\}$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} L(P_{n},f) = \lim_{n\to\infty} U(P_{n}, f)$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} L(Q_{n},g) = \lim_{n\to\infty} U(Q_{n}, g)$$

Let $R_{n} = P_{n} \cup Q_{n}$. Since $R_{n}$ is a refinement of $P_{n}$ the following holds :

$$L(P_{n},f) \le L(R_{n},f) \le U(R_{n}, f) \le U(P_{n}, f)$$. By the squeeze theorem, we have that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} L(R_{n},f) = \lim_{n\to\infty} U(R_{n}, f)$$

And similarly

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} L(R_{n},g) = \lim_{n\to\infty} U(R_{n}, g)$$

We note that

$$L(R_n , f) + L(R_n , g) \le  L(R_n , f+g) \le U(R_n , f+g) \le U(R_n , f) + U(R_n , g)$$

By the squeeze theorem, we have that $\lim_{n\to \infty} L(R_n , f+g) = \lim_{n\to \infty} U(R_n , f+g) = \lim_{n\to \infty} L(R_n , f) +\lim_{n\to \infty} L(R_n , g)$. Hence it follows that $\int_{a}^{b}( f+g) = \int_{a}^{b} f + \int_{a}^{b} g$

---

Is this proof correct? Here's the textbook proof:

[image]

Comment: I would say it is.

Comment: Minor quibble: your proof is is fine once you prove that reducing the collection of $arbitrary$ partitions to your system $\{ P _n\}$ is valid, which amounts to proving that if $f$ is Riemann integrable, then for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $P$ is a partition, with mesh $\Delta x<\delta$, then $|\int f-U(P,f)|<\epsilon.$

Comment: @Matematleta Hey I am not sure if your comment makes much sense to me (since this is my first course in analysis) but isn't it equivalent that there is a sequence of partitions ${P_n}$ such that $\lim L(P_n , f) = \lim U(P_n , f)$ to saying $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not, in general, have that $L(f,P)+L(g,P)=L(f+g,P)$ or that $U(f,P)+U(g,P)=U(f+g,P)$ - the infs and sups can happen in different places between the two functions. When you combine the functions, there needs to be an inequality there. After all, it's possible for the sum of functions to be integrable even if neither of the original functions were. By not addressing this, your argument fails.

Now that the argument has been edited, it works.

Comment: I was being silly. Let me fix my proof.

Comment: Hey is it okay now?

Comment: Yes, it works now.